# Where is logs files of containerd?

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I am using crictl pull to pull images, but it hangs at PullImageRequest.
I want to know what is happenning, so
Where is logs files of containerd, not logs of containers running but logs of containerd itself

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`containerd` is running as a service of Linux, so you can check its logs with `journalctl -u containerd`.

Answer (score 6):

Also in Containerd (as CRI) you can find containers log in `/var/log/pods/` path.